# get the content of a const void

Tags: c, pointers, constants, void

I'm trying to get the value of the data pointed by a const void pointer.
I've wrote this simple example in order to get the different way.
But for some reason it won't work.Actually I want the printf to write "data 5 and the address of the pointer "
Can someone please help me ?

Thanks

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    const void * data;
    int b = 5;
    data = &b;
    printf("data %d %p ",&data,&data);
}
```

Comment: If you want to interpret data, you need to know (and thus give it) its *type*. Don't use `void`. C does not have a built-in mechanism for identifying the type of data outside of the static type system.

Comment: `printf("data %d %p ", *(const int*)data, &data);`

Comment: The "*(const int*)" before the data solve this thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` holds the address of `b`. To print out that address with `%p` just pass `data`. `&data` is is the address of `data` rather than the address of `b`.

To get the value at that address you need to dereference `data` with `*data`. But there's a catch. You can't dereference `void` pointers because their data type is unknown. To get the `int` value at that address you need to cast the `const void *` to `const int *` first. Then you can dereference the result.

```
printf("data %d %p\n", *(const int *) data, data);
```